# Setting Up Replication/master slave configuration to mariaDB

Tags: database-administration, mariadb, build-server

I'm starting my project using ***mariaDB***

1. I want to setup *master slave* configurations on windows 7 64Bit. I don't know how to setup this kind of configuration.

I've searched on google, visited websites and blogs, i find a term **buildbot**, is it related to master slave setup in mariaDB. ?
If my question has another solved answer please tell me so that i can move further. Thanks in advance. hope for positive response.

Answer (score 0):

As mariaDB is still a [drop-in replacement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) for the same MySQL version, you can start by reading MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) regarding replication as it will enlighten you about this specific topic.